# Why does my phpMyAdmin keep downloading a file without extension called "download"?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 22.04. Inside that I installed XAMPP or in this case it's LAMPP actually so I can run the web server and everything like I run them on localhost. The apache from LAMPP works totally fine and so does the MySQL and the phpMyAdmin.

But at the first time after I installed LAMPP, I couldn't access phpMyAdmin, it returned Forbidden error. I saw a solution (sorry I can't find it where because I was browsing in incognito) that I need to change the `httpd-xampp.conf` file on `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/`. The solution was I need to comment the `LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl` and change the `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` syntax to this:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

This works, but when I want to access the phpMyAdmin like this: `www.example.com/phpmyadmin`, it keeps downloading a file without extension called "downoad". But if I access it like this `www.example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php`, it works fine and doesn't download a file.

This is what inside that file:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;

if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}

global $route, $containerBuilder;

require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';

$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

How could this happen? And how to solve it?

Thank you.